# Find the matrix of Linear Operator $A$ in other basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

The matrix of Linear operator A in the basis $\{ e_1,e_2,e_3 \}$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}    1 & 2 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$
how shall i find the matrix of this linear opeartor in the basis $\{ e_2, e_1, e_3 \}$
do i have to just change the order of lines, or is there a special algorithm to  calculate the matrix in other basis?

Comment: You would have to change the order of columns. The easiest way to see this is to note that the columns of the matrix of $A$ are the images of the basis vectors under transformation $A$.

Comment: You can probably figure out by asking yourself: What does that linear operator do to a vector in the given basis? And what _should_ it do to a vector in the new basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $A$ the given matrix in the basis $B=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and let $B'=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ your second basis. Let $P$ the change matrix from $B$ to $B'$, then the matrix in the basis $B'$ is $P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: I think that, besides the general formula, it may be a good think to note that the particular case that interests the author does not require any calculations.